# Modify a python script with bash and execute it with the changes

Tags: python, bash

I have a python script that is a command-line interface. I execute it from a bash script that saves the output in a txt file:

```
#!/bin/bash

for ... in ...
do
    echo "Foo:$foo"
    echo "Bar:$bar"
    ./pythonScript.py --argument1 "arg"
    # make changes
done
```

What I want to do is modify a specific line of the python script and execute it again with the new line changed until the for loop finishes.

The piece of code from the python script that I want to change is similar to that:

```
QUERY = 'www.foo.com' + '/bar?' \
        + '&title=%(title)s' \
        + '&start=0' \
        + '&num=%(num)s'
```

The `start` parameter of the query must be increased by 20 units every time the for loop is executed. So, after 5 executions `start` should be 100.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Any reason why you can't implement it as a second argument to the python script?

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you can't just do everything in python?

Comment: @MatsLindh No, it could be perfectly done in that way

Comment: @M.T I have been doing it in bash and I can't change it now

Comment: @Oscar Keep track of the iteration count in bash and give start as a parameter to the python script.

Comment: You should really spank the person who came up with the idea of generating Python code from Bash :-) You probably have some project constraints that prevent you from fixing your Python code now, but in that case you could point out to the person in charge that this is technical debt that will often take more effort to fix in the future. It's like with an unwanted tree, you want to cut it down as long as it is small.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As multiple comments have already suggested, don't do that.  Change the Python script so that it accepts a second parameter instead.  Modifying your code on the fly is brittle and complex, and the standard solution to that is to parametrize the things you want to change.

```
QUERY = 'www.foo.com' + '/bar?' \
        + '&title=%(title)s' \
        + '&start=%(start)i' \
        + '&num=%(num)s'
```

Then run the loop something like

```
start=0
for ... in ...
do
    echo "Foo:$foo"
    echo "Bar:$bar"
    ./pythonScript.py --argument1 "arg" --start "$start"
    ((start += 20))  # bash only
done
```

Answer (score 0):

what you need is just a loop?

```
start = 0

for i in range(5)
    QUERY = 'www.foo.com' + '/bar?' + 
            '&title=%(title)s' +
            '&start=' + start +
            '&num=%(num)s'
    print(QUERY)
    start += 20
```